# How can I user json to dispaly in laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel

i tried to view data from database as per shown but get this error

```
    $testjson = new TestJson ;
    $testjson = $testjson->Where('id',2)->get();
    return view('viewjson')->with('alldata',Json_decode($testjson));
```

user below code to view data

```
@foreach($alldata as $key => $value)
    {{ $key }} - {{ $value }} <br>
@endforeach
```

can't get scope data
0 - {"id":2,"token":"2020-04-06 12:02:15",**"data":"{\"scope\":[\"volvo\",\"saab\",\"opel\",\"audi\"]}"**,"created_at":"2020-04-06 12:02:15","updated_at":"2020-04-06 12:02:15"}

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVaE8.png)

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Looks like a double-encoded json. Since we don't know exactly where this issue is happening, we can't help you too much

Answer (score 0):

```
$testjson = new TestJson ;
$testjson = $testjson->Where('id',2)->get();
return response()->json(['data' =>  $testjson]);
```

Comment: how get data in data->scope
,"data":"{\"scope\":[\"volvo\",\"saab\",\"opel\",\"audi\"]}",


{"id":2,"token":"2020-04-06 12:02:15","data":"{\"scope\":[\"volvo\",\"saab\",\"opel\",\"audi\"]}","created_at":"2020-04-06 12:02:15","updated_at":"2020-04-06 12:02:15"}

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying in laravel view then no need to convert in json

```
$alldata = TestJson::find(2);
return view('viewjson', compact('alldata'));
```

And in laravel view

```
@foreach($alldata ?? [] as $key => $value)
    @if($key == 'data')
       @foreach(json_decode($value->data) ?? [] as $innerKey => $innerValue)
             {{ $innerKey }} - {{ $innerValue}} <br>
       @endforeach
    @else
       {{ $key }} - {{ $value }} <br>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: i got this values

{"id":2,"token":"2020-04-06 12:02:15","data":"{\"scope\":[\"volvo\",\"saab\",\"opel\",\"audi\"]}","created_at":"2020-04-06 12:02:15","updated_at":"2020-04-06 12:02:15"} 

still can't get scope values

Comment: it is because you put `Json_decode` remove that and check again.

Comment: i used it to insert multi values in same col

<select multiple>

Comment: now i put image from database and how can view column "data"